# How to get the contents of specific cells in Google Scripting?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet I created using Google Spreadsheets. It is for attendance to meetings. Each meeting holds a value and all the values are added together to give you a total. I want to have a switch statement that says,

```
for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
  if(cell in each column contains 'X'){
    switch(column[i])
        case 1:
            column[0]=meeting1;
            pointValue=5;
            break;
        case 2:
            column[1]=meeting2;
            pointValue=3;
            break;
  }
// add all the points up and place them next to the name in another spreadsheet
```

The above code is all pseudo.

Essentially, how do I 'get' specific cells in the Google Scripting?

Comment: Tag as apps script. See samples there are lots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is by:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols);
// and later, when you wish to update these cells
dataRange.setValues(newData);
```

For more try https://github.com/greenido/AppsScriptBests - It's a repo that I try to keep updated with good examples.